# grammars on "shoot me an email" vs "shoot me with an email"

Tags: idioms, transitivity, ditransitive-verbs

According to several online pages, there are different grammatical interpretations of the structure of the phrase - `shoot someone an email`. To complicate it further, I've seen online a similar phrase "shoot me **with** an email", although it is possible that the users are not native English speakers.

I am seeking some clarification, if possible, or consensus in this ESL community regarding these two phrases and the grammars behind it/them.

In all structures, the verb `to shoot` seems to be used as a transitive verb. However,

> structure 1: shoot (someone) an email - email being the action object.
>
> structure 2: shoot someone an email - double objects
>
> structure 3: shoot someone with an email - someone being the action object.

Q1. Are all three correct English sentences ?

Q2. It seems unusual for the verb "`to shoot`" to be followed by double objects. Is it limited to the "borrowed definition" of `to send` ?

Q3. what are the differences, if any, between sentences 1 and 2 and between sentences 2 and 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

OP's examples are very slangy usages (not appropriate in all contexts, so be *very* careful about using them yourself), where idiomatically the preposition is required with

> ***Hit*** me **with** an email
>    but not with
>    ***Shoot*** me an email.

That's because when ***shoot*** means ***send***, it's *ditransitive* (it can take ***both*** a direct ***and*** an indirect object at the same time, without using prepositions for either. Note that the second example *could* be rephrased to use a preposition *(Shoot an email **to** me)*, just as we can choose to say either *Give me the ball* or *Give the ball **to** me*.

---

(Note that *Shoot me **with** an email* isn't idiomatically valid. It could only have come from a non-native speaker, which is *precisely* why I gave that warning in my first sentence above! :)